# Help me to set up equation for FindRoot to solve

Tags: equation-solving

When I run the code I get this error message:

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Eq1 - 0.08*Eq2} is not a list of  numbers with dimensions {1} at {d} = {0.001}.

How can I correct the error and find the value for `d`? And also I don't know how many roots can Eqt has.

```
(*initial values to obtain the root*)
a = 7.06; b = 0; c = 0.107763;

(*defining the equations*)
Eq1 [d_?NumericQ] := 
   Eq1[d]= Simplify[((a-b)*((628*d)^(1-c))*Cos[c*Pi/2])];
Eq2 [d_?NumericQ] := 
   Eq2[d] = Simplify[(1+2*((628*d)^(1-c))*Sin[c*Pi/2]+((628*d)^(2*(1-c)))];

(*define the equation which the root must be calculated*)
Eqt = Evaluate[Eq1 - 0.08*Eq2 == 0];
(*here I like to find the root d*)
FindRoot[Eqt, {d, 0.001}]
```

Comment: Writing `Eqt = Evaluate[Eq1[d] - 0.08*Eq2[d] == 0]` will fix the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = 7.06; b = 0; c = 0.107763;(*initial values to obtain the root*)(*defining the equations*)

Eq1 = ((a - b)*((628*d)^(1 - c))*Cos[c*Pi/2]);
Eq2 = 1 + 2*((628*d)^(1 - c))*Sin[c*Pi/2] + ((628*d)^(2*(1 - c)));
(*define the equation which the root must be calculated*)

Eqt = Eq1 - 0.08*Eq2 == 0;
FindRoot[Eqt, {d, 1/10000}]

(* {d -> 0.0000107223 } *) 

FindRoot[Eqt, {d, 1/2}]

(*{d -> 0.23648} *)
```

If `d` is `Real` we have only 2 roots:

```
NSolve[Eqt && -100 < d < 100, d, Reals]
{{d -> 0.0000107223}, {d -> 0.23648}}
```

**EDITED:**

It is better to use exact numbers for that use `Rationalize[0.265616, 0]` function.

```
a = 7013/500;(*14.026*)
b = 241/25000000;(*9.64*10^(-6)*)
c = 16601/62500;(*0.265616*)
Eq1 = ((a - b)*((628*d)^(1 - c))*Cos[c*Pi/2]);
Eq2 = 1 + 2*((628*d)^(1 - c))*Sin[c*Pi/2] + ((628*d)^(2*(1 - c)));
Eqt = Eq1 - 8/100*Eq2 == 0;
sol = FindRoot[Eqt, {d, 1/10}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(*{d -> 1.59474734438386133056761886005121544936415083334269688311103192\
8277447098063374108097226699429567875*10^-6 - 
3.11673146273605497900349372926910978847189125527343938927043516405\
9118848431652462070982280427383199*10^-117 I}*)

sol // Chop
(*{d -> 1.59474734438386133056761886005121544936415083334269688311103192\
8277447098063374108097226699429567875*10^-6}*)
```

Comment: Or  `Solve[Eqt, d, Reals]` .

Comment: Thanks, @Mariusz Iwaniuk the script worked out. I have tried the script for other initial values a = 14.026; b = 9.64*10^(-6); c = 0.265616; and I get imaginary numbers for the roots. Can you help me to figure out why the roots are imaginary numbers?

Comment: @Nini. In general any Mathematica function, works on complex numbers by default.Since the values have some precision, there will be small complex noise, which you can get rid of with `Chop[]` if you are so inclined.Try executed this code: `Precision[7.06]` and `?MachinePrecision` and read in Documentation for more information.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I guessed where to insert a missing `)` in Eq2. If that was right then

```
Plot[ReIm[Eq1[d]-0.08*Eq2[d]],{d,-1/2,1/2}]
```

shows you approximately where the two roots are so you can give `FindRoot` good starting estimates.

Comment: Hi @Bill the code you provided doesn't give me any results. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @Bill, I copied this code and ran it. It gives a graph without any data points on it.

Comment: Hi @Bill, it is fine. I am using version 8. I haven't tried other functions. I don't know any of them to give me similar results. If you can give me suggestions it will be fantastic.

Comment: Ah! That was the clue. If you look at the bottom of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html?q=ReIm you should see that `ReIm` was introduced in version 10.1 which is why version 8 doesn't understand it. Hopefully this `a=7013/500;b=241/25000000;c=16601/62500; Eq1[t_]:=((a-b)*((628*d)^(1-c))*Cos[c*Pi/2]); Eq2[t_]:=1+2*((628*d)^(1-c))*Sin[c*Pi/2]+((628*d)^(2*(1-c))); Plot[{Re[Eq1[d]-0.08*Eq2[d]],Im[Eq1[d]-0.08*Eq2[d]]},{d,-1/2,1/2}]` should work for you in version 8

Comment: Hi @Bill, the code worked. Thanks!